# Error al agregar la librería sqlite-net-pcl al proyecto Android de mi solución

Tags: .net, sqlite, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Tengo un proyecto .NET Xamarin en el que uso SQLite para almacenar unos datos. Cuando se ejecuta, aparece un mensaje en la pantalla del dispositivo virtual que uso para emular android un mensaje como "Unfortunately [app] has stopped". He investigado muchísimo y no he encontrado solución.

**Tratando de reproducir el error**

El asunto es que, mientras indagaba, decidí, para saber si es el agregar la librería mencionada es lo que produce el error, crear un nuevo proyecto de Xamarin.Forms  desde cero dejando todo tal cual como te lo genera Visual Studio, que es con el MainPage.xaml (el cual contiene la frase "Welcome to Xamarin.Forms"). Luego, le agregué la librería *sqlite-net-pcl* al proyecto general y al proyecto Android. Cuando lo ejecuto, me sale exactamente el mismo error en la pantalla del dispositivo emulado: "Unfortunately [app] has stopped"; pero esta vez me percato de la pestaña *Output* de Visual Studio y observo el siguiente error:

```
Android application is debugging.
12-27 22:55:20.021 I/art     ( 3398): Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
12-27 22:55:20.084 D/AndroidRuntime( 3398): Shutting down VM
12-27 22:55:20.084 E/AndroidRuntime( 3398): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-27 22:55:20.084 E/AndroidRuntime( 3398): Process: com.companyname.StoringCollection1, PID: 3398
12-27 22:55:20.084 E/AndroidRuntime( 3398): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.companyname.StoringCollection1-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.companyname.StoringCollection1-1/lib/x86_64, /data/app/com.companyname.StoringCollection1-1/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libmonodroid.so"
12-27 22:55:20.084 E/AndroidRuntime( 3398):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
12-27 22:55:20.084 E/AndroidRuntime( 3398):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
12-27 22:55:20.084 E/AndroidRuntime( 3398):     at mono.MonoPackageManager.LoadApplication(MonoPackageManager.java:34)
12-27 22:55:20.084 E/AndroidRuntime( 3398):     at mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:42)
12-27 22:55:20.084 E/AndroidRuntime( 3398):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5153)
12-27 22:55:20.084 E/AndroidRuntime( 3398):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748)
12-27 22:55:20.084 E/AndroidRuntime( 3398):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688)
12-27 22:55:20.084 E/AndroidRuntime( 3398):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
12-27 22:55:20.084 E/AndroidRuntime( 3398):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
12-27 22:55:20.084 E/AndroidRuntime( 3398):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-27 22:55:20.084 E/AndroidRuntime( 3398):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-27 22:55:20.084 E/AndroidRuntime( 3398):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
12-27 22:55:20.084 E/AndroidRuntime( 3398):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-27 22:55:20.084 E/AndroidRuntime( 3398):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
12-27 22:55:20.084 E/AndroidRuntime( 3398):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Hay algo que cabe mencionar: la pestaña *Error List* no me indica alguna anomalía, sencillamente se encuentra vacía.

**Consideraciones**

- Hago uso de Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017, versión 15.4.4
- Versión de .NET Framewor: 4.7.02046
- Detalles de la libreria sqlite-net-pcl que instalé en el proyecto Android y el general (no estoy haciendo uso del proyecto iOS ni el UWP):

  - Versión: 1.4.118 (creo que la última disponible hasta ahora).
  - Autor: Frank A.Krueger.
  - Fecha de publicación: Thursday, July 27, 2017 (7/27/2017).
- Me he encontrado con el [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186726/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-dalvik-system-pathclassloader) hilo, el cual, al parecer, por lo novato que soy, no puedo lograr reproducir la solución que ofrece.
- También me topé con [esta publicación](https://medium.com/mobiwise-blog/unsatisfiedlinkerror-problem-on-some-android-devices-b77f2f83837d). Creo que si pudiera seguir los pasos que indica lo solucionaría, pero al parecer soy demasiado nuevo en todo esto de programación móvil.

Comment: Empieza por lo simple. Elimina las carpetas bin/obj del proyecto. Revisa que el la versión de la PCL sea compatible con el nuget de SQLite. Quita el nuget de SQLite y comprueba que la App arranca. Prueba con los emuladores de Genymotion y si continuas igual, reinstala Xamarin.